# How to find number of common tangents between two curves

Tags: conic-sections, curves, algebraic-curves

how can I find the number of common tangents between two general degree curves , I have been solving many question regarding find the number common tangents between parabola and circle or ellipse and hyperbola or whatever combinations I can think of , So I was wondering whether a generalised condition can be obtained to find no. of common tangents?

Comment: not sure what a common tangent means in this context? same line being tangent to both curves at the same point? at different points? different lines at same point?

Comment: These are difficult problems in "a generalized condition".  One needs specific details in order to say much about a line which is tangent to two curves.  Often a parameterization of the curves, and the associated parametrization of their tangents, is a good starting point.

Comment: Given plane curves of degrees $d_1$ and $d_2$. The number of common tangents is the number of intersection points of the dual curves. This is given by Bezout: $d_1(d_1-1)d_2(d_2-1).$